# Spring Boot & Kerberos - KrbException: no supported default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos

I am using **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE** app to send messages to **Kafka 0.11** using Kerberos authentication. 
This is my `kafka-jaas.conf`:

```
KafkaClient{
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=true
  keyTab="/home/tomi/user-matXp.com.keytab"
  principal="user/matXp.com@COM";
};
```

And `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: "kafka-server.com:9092"
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    properties:
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
      sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
```

I'm starting app like this:

```
-java -jar -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/tomi/kafka-jaas.conf
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/tomi/krb5.conf 
kafka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &> output.log&
```

When trying to send message I get `sun.security.krb5.KrbException: no supported default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes`.

In my `krb5.conf` `default_tkt_enctypes` is defined to `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`.
I have tried to comment out that line in krb5.conf but then I get `sun.security.krb5.Asn1Exception: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can help you fix this.  Do you still have the command syntax you used to create the keytab handy?  If so, post that here as an edit into your question.

Comment: The Kerberos and Kafka are in a different system, so we didn't create the keytab.
I've posted the solution. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the JCE Unlimited Strength Policy wasn't included. It's disabled by default.

The solution was to uncomment `crypto.policy=unlimited` in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`. 
This can also be done in app with `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");`.